# How to view the systemd-xdg-autostart-generator generated files?

Tags: debian, systemd

I ran the following command:

```
$ systemctl --user list-dependencies xdg-desktop-autostart.target
xdg-desktop-autostart.target
○ ├─app-geoclue\x2ddemo\x2dagent@autostart.service
○ ├─app-gnome\x2dinitial\x2dsetup\x2dfirst\x2dlogin@autostart.service
○ ├─app-gnome\x2dshell\x2doverrides\x2dmigration@autostart.service
○ ├─app-im\x2dlaunch@autostart.service
○ ├─app-nemo\x2ddesktop@autostart.service
○ ├─app-nm\x2dapplet@autostart.service
○ ├─app-orca\x2dautostart@autostart.service
○ ├─app-org.gnome.Evolution\x2dalarm\x2dnotify@autostart.service
○ ├─app-org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.DiskUtilityNotify@autostart.service
○ ├─app-org.gnome.Software@autostart.service
○ ├─app-user\x2ddirs\x2dupdate\x2dgtk@autostart.service
○ ├─app-xdg\x2duser\x2ddirs\x2dkde@autostart.service
○ └─app-yandex\x2ddisk@autostart.service
```

Here I want to know the location of the given files, mainly `app-nemo\x2ddesktop@autostart.service` (so that I can view the content of the file).

I have checked [systemd-xdg-autostart-generator](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-xdg-autostart-generator.html) documentation. Could not find any hint.

How can I do that?

Comment: I don't know if the auto-generated services actually exist on disk anywhere, but `systemd cat whatever.service` will show the contents

Comment: cat does not show anything but `systemctl --user show app-nemo\x2ddesktop@autostart.service` does. However, it seems incomplete. I mean it does not have `ExecStart`, `WantedBy` etc.

Comment: In my machine, i found the files in `/run/user/1000/systemd/generator.late`

Comment: the command to get to this solution is `systemctl --user edit "app-nemo\x2ddesktop@autostart.service"`